# Непредвиденная ошибка при обращении к несуществующему элементу массива (константа класса)

Tags: php, классы, php5, константа

У меня есть небольшой класс в котором я использую внутреннюю константу (массив) для получения имени метода по классу объекта:

```
class Synchronize implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Observable class names with corresponding methods.
     */
    const CLASS_MAPPER = [
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order' => 'syncOrderData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice' => 'syncInvoiceData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Track' => 'syncShipmentTrackData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment' => 'syncShipmentData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address' => 'syncAddressData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item' => 'syncItemsData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Tax' => 'syncTaxData'
    ];

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        /** @see \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::_getEventData() */
        $object = $event->getDataObject();
        if (!is_object($object) || empty(static::CLASS_MAPPER[get_class($object)])) {
            return $this;
        }

        $this->{static::CLASS_MAPPER[get_class($object)]}($object);

        return $this;
    }

    //...
}
```

Проблема возникает когда в `$object` приходит объект с классом которого нет в списке `static::CLASS_MAPPER`. Возникает нотис примерно следующего содержания:

> Notice: Undefined index: MageWorx\OrderEditor\Model\Order\Item in /home/asys/web/m212ee2/app/code/MageWorx/OrdersGrid/Observer/Synchronize.php on line 80

Сама ошибка в принципе мне понятна, и альтернативные пути решения проблемы существуют, но я не могу разобраться, **по какой причине вызов `empty(get_class($object))` вызывает нотис если такого элемента не существует?**

Судя из [описания на php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php) нотис не должен возникать при вызове `empty()`:

> Проверяет, считается ли переменная пустой. Переменная считается пустой, если она не существует или её значение равно FALSE. empty() не генерирует предупреждение, если переменная не существует.

---

> Если переменная не существует, предупреждение не генерируется. Это значит, что empty() фактически является точным эквивалентом конструкции !isset($var) || $var == false

Буду признателен, если кто-нибудь сможет прояснить для меня такое поведение php.

**PS:** Версия php **5.6**

**PPS:** Вот линк для проверки кода онлайн, где на версии 5.6 падает нотис, но на версии >= 7 уже не падает:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/43ef701f65c5137a10ffae32bfa7e3a2c564a651

**PPPS:** каких-либо ограничений для версии 5.6 отличных от версии >= 7 в описании `empty()` я не нашел :( Возможно причина в других изменениях в php?

**Код для тестов:**

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class Synchronize
{
    /**
     * Observable class names with corresponding methods.
     */
    const CLASS_MAPPER = [
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order' => 'syncOrderData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice' => 'syncInvoiceData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Track' => 'syncShipmentTrackData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment' => 'syncShipmentData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address' => 'syncAddressData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item' => 'syncItemsData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Tax' => 'syncTaxData'
    ];

    public function execute()
    {
        $objClass = 'MageWorx\OrderEditor\Model\Order\Item';
        if (empty(static::CLASS_MAPPER[$objClass])) {
            echo 'A';
        } else {
            echo 'B';
        }
    }
}

echo 'Start >>> ';

$a = new \Synchronize();
$a->execute();

echo ' >>> End';
```

В моем тесте ответ php 7.0:

> Start >>> A >>> End

Ответ php 5.6:

> [image: Ответ php 5.6]

Comment: замените этот вариант `empty(get_class($object))` на этот: `$obj = get_class($object);  empty($obj)`

Comment: @Эдуард Спасибо за комментарий. К сожалению это не приведет к желаемому результату и ошибка останется. Если вы откроете сэндбокс http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/43ef701f65c5137a10ffae32bfa7e3a2c564a651 то увидите, что там обращение идет просто строкой к константе-массиву, ошибка всеравно остается :( Я не могу понять причину по которой вызов `empty(static::CLASS_MAPPER[$obj])` вызывает ошибку уровня notice. Аналогичное вашему обходное решение я уже нашел: `$class = get_class($object);
        if (!array_key_exists($class, static::CLASS_MAPPER)) {...` но ищу причину такого поведения.

Comment: в конструкции empty() насколько я помню, надо записывать только переменные. Попробуйте сохранить в переменную значение константы, и эту переменную прописать в empty().

Comment: @Эдуард Спасибо за комментарий. Так было до версии 5.5, исходя из документации: *До PHP 5.5 empty() проверяет только переменные, и попытка проверить что-то еще вызовет ошибку синтаксиса.* теперь же проверять можно любое выражение.

Comment: так у вас ключ MageWorx\OrderEditor\Model\Order\Item, в вашем массиве его нет вот и ошибка. empty тут не при чем. static::CLASS_MAPPER[get_class($object)] - вот тут возникает нотис

Comment: @JurijJazdanov если это так, то по какой причине это не так в `php 7.0`? Сейчас у меня на сервере включен *PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )* и вызвать эту ошибку я не могу таким же образом. Я добавлю небольшой тестовый код в мой вопрос, что бы вам было легче ее воспроизвести, если вы пожелаете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы может не использовать константу

```
<?php
class A
{
    private $classMapper = [
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order' => 'syncOrderData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice' => 'syncInvoiceData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Track' => 'syncShipmentTrackData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment' => 'syncShipmentData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address' => 'syncAddressData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item' => 'syncItemsData',
        'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Tax' => 'syncTaxData',
    ];

    public function isExists($val)
    {
        return (int)!empty($this->classMapper[$val]);
    }
}

$a = new A();
echo $a->isExists('Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Item\\Interceptor');
```

И тогда все будет ок, возможно это какой-то баг в 5.6 связанный с empty, константами и массивами так как именно с этой версии в константы можно писать массивы, а в 7й видимо баг исправили.

В 2015-ом был [репорт](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70884&edit=1) с багом но его закрыли из-за неактуальности на тот момент, добавил новый [репорт](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75984) так как ошибка все ещё существует, посмотрим что ответят.

---

Пришел ответ:

> This bug has already been fixed in recent versions of PHP as you can
>   see in the 3v4l.org link you posted.
>
> The version you're using (5.6.x) is in security-only support mode. No
>   further bug fixes are provided for that version. Please upgrade to a
>   newer version of PHP.

Бага в 7-ой версии уже нет, а в версии 5.6 баги фиксить не будут(кроме проблем с безопасностью).

Получается что вопрос закрыт.

**З.Ы.**
Кстати я бы тоже не реккомендовал использовать устаревшую версию, сами давно перевели все на 7-ку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, все же хотелось бы узнать истинную причину такого поведения php. В моем случае я решил проблему подобным образом (`foreach` по массиву с проверкой `instanceof`), но возможно изменю решение когда пойму причины :(

Comment: Этот баг уже добавляли в трекер но закрыли так как он был неактуален, добавил новый репорт - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75984 посмотрим что ответят.

Comment: Спасибо. Оставил там свой голос, надеюсь исправят :) Хотя изза его наличия всеравно придется не использовать изначальный вариант кода, т.к. у многих клиентов для которых он предназначен может быть эта версия php :( Не могли бы вы добавить информацию из вашего комментария к ответу (и ссылку на старый баг если это возможно)?